# JSON parse using JSON from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I use a webservice to create a PHP array **$result**, but when passed to javascript and JSON.parse, nothing results. I am a newbie with php and JS arrays, have done much googling, but cannot find the answer. Help welcome!

First the output in a browser, where the PHP array prints out, but the javascript does not output anything:-

```
1) Results of PHP array print
Array
(
    [hotels] => Array
        (
            [codigo] => LIMHBM
            [fecha] => 2016/9/15
            [cannoc] => 1
            [canhab] => 1
            [canpax] => 2
            [estado] => OK
        )

)
2) Results of JSON parse: none
```

The relevant code part:-

```
1) Results of PHP array print
<pre><?php print_r($result); ?></pre>

2) Results of JSON parse: 
<span id="demo">none</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
var result = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($result) ?>' );
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result.hotels[0].codigo + " " + result.hotels[0].estado;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code is right till the last line of javascript code which is:-

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result.hotels[0].codigo + " " + result.hotels[0].estado;
```

Change it to:-

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result.hotels.codigo+ " " + result.hotels.estado;
```

Example:-

```
<?php 

$result = Array
(
    'hotels' => Array
        (
            'codigo' => 'LIMHBM',
            'fecha' => '2016/9/15',
            'cannoc' => 1,
            'canhab' => 1,
            'canpax' => 2,
            'estado' => 'OK'
        )

);
?>
1) Results of PHP array print
<?php echo "<pre/>";print_r($result); ?>

2) Results of JSON parse: 
<span id="demo">none</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
var result =  JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($result) ?>');
console.log(result); // to just show you te output in console
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result.hotels.codigo+ " " + result.hotels.estado;
</script>
```

Output:-  http://prntscr.com/avm729

For multidimensional array help, check this:-

http://prntscr.com/avmcp3

Comment: Great, this worked fine, and is the answer as far as I'm concerned. If instead of one hotel within the 'hotels' array, there are several, would it then be correct to use codigo[1], estado[1] etc?

Comment: Yes then you need to go for that.

Comment: Thanks again, perfect!

Comment: Thanks again Anant, I checked out with several hotels and that worked too. One last question, don't answer if a nuisance, but if there are several hotels, how to search for say the codigo LIMBXX amongst the results?

Comment: @Paul  search for `javascript  loop on array` concept on google. some spelling correction and then you will find out lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

This bit is pointless:

```
var result = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($result) ?>' );
```

JSON is already valid javascript, so there's **NO** need to parse it. All you need to do is dump it out directly into the code block:

```
var result = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
```